# How to return a float array in java

Tags: arrays, return

This is my code:

```
public  float[] DataSet() {
  float[] Data = {1.51,2.35,3.36};
  return  Data;}
```

Why do I get the error message:

> This method must return a result of type float[]

Answer (score 2):

The literals, 1.51 etc. are implicitly `double`. That's how Java interprets them.

See [Primitive data types in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

If you want a float array, try postfixing them with `f`.

`float[] Data = {1.51f, 2.35f, 3.36f};`

Answer (score 0):

The values inside array are doubles. You could for example do this:

```
public float[] DataSet() {
    float[] Data = {1.51f,2.35f,3.36f};
    return  Data;
}
```